# Command in Unix to count number of occurrences of a specific word

Tags: unix

I want to search Exact word pattern in Unix,

Example : Log.txt file contains following text :

```
aaa         (only this 'aaa' pattern shhold be counted)
bbb
cccaaa   ---> this should not be counted in grep output
ccc_aaa   --> this should not be counted in grep output
ccc-aaa   --> this should not be counted in grep output
ccc.aaa   ---> this should not be counted in grep output
```

I am using following code-

```
count=$?
count=$(grep -c -w aaa $ZZZ\Log.txt)
```

Here output should be ==> 1 but i m getting 4 as output, I think, something is missing So, can any one help me for the this please?

Comment: If you want to match *only* aaa, use ^aaa$ for the pattern.

Comment: Squiguy, Kelvin : Thnak you very much for your answeres

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `-x` option.  Here is the excerpt from the man page which is always the quickest way to find a solution for the options.

```
-x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
          (-x is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample input, I would expect the output to be 3.  One for the line you expect, one for `ccc-aaa` and one for `ccc.aaa`.  The grep documentation clearly states that word characters are letters, digits, and underscore.  If you want to consider `.` and `-` as word constituent characters, just pre-filter the data:

```
count=$( tr < $ZZZ/Log.txt .- ' '  | grep -c -w aaa )
```

The above uses `tr` to convert occurrences of `.` and `-` to spaces.  You may want to expand the set of characters that you want to consider, depending on your needs.